# What optimization is making my rust program so much faster?

Tags: rust

Frustrated that I could not solve a Sudoku puzzle, I quickly hacked together a simple recursive backtracking solver:

```
fn is_allowed(board: &[[u8; 9]; 9], row: usize, col: usize, x: u8) -> bool {
    for i in 0..9 {
        if board[row][i] == x {
            return false;
        }
        if board[i][col] == x {
            return false;
        }
    }

    let r = row - (row % 3);
    let c = col - (col % 3);
    for i in r..(r + 3) {
        for j in c..(c + 3) {
            if board[i][j] == x {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    true
}

fn solve(board: &mut [[u8; 9]; 9]) -> bool {
    for i in 0..9 {
        for j in 0..9 {
            if board[i][j] == 0 {
                for x in 1..=9 {
                    if is_allowed(board, i, j, x) {
                        board[i][j] = x;
                        if solve(board) {
                            return true
                        }
                        board[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    let mut board = [
        [ 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7 ],
        [ 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 9 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 2, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0 ],
    ];

    if solve(&mut board) {
        for i in 0..9 {
            println!("{:?}", board[i]);
        }
    } else {
        println!("no solution");
    }
}
```

When running without optimizations (`cargo run`), it takes more than 6 minutes to run.

When running with optimizations (`cargo run --release`), it takes about 7 seconds to run.

What optimization is leading to such a difference?

Comment: FWIW, the C++ Sudoku solver I wrote to teach people how to solve Sudoku takes about 3 milliseconds to solve this same problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Cool! It's definitely not great code as written, but I was mainly curious in the compiler optimization that caused the massive disparity

Comment: Very related: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: You can copy/paste your code into an online compiler, such as godbolt or the Rust playground, which allows you to inspect the LLVM IR or the assembly. godbolt is able to match the assembly statements to the code portion, so can be a bit easier. There you'll see what clever optimizations the compiler pulled off... if you can recognize them.

Comment: I plugged your example into [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ylko6t). Removing `print` as it bloats the output.

Comment: IMHO the main issue is that without optimization all variables are kept on the stack instead of in registers, which adds a lot of instructions which do relatively slow memory accesses. Try optimization level 1, which does simple optimizations but AFAIK doesn't reorder code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to be sure without analyzing the generated assembly, but I think that it is related to the combination of these optimizations:

- Loop unrolling: the compiler knows that each loop runs 8 times, so instead of a loop it compiles the loop body 8 times with the index as a constant. This is why the *godbold* link by @MatthieuM in the comments above is so long.
- Range checking: since `i`, `j` and `k` are now constants (in the unrolled loops) and the arrays are of known size, the compiler will omit all range checks.
- Function inlining.

In fact, each time you write `board[i][j]`:

- In debug mode, you are calling two library functions that do checkings and computations.
- In release mode each instance of such code is just a read or write to fixed offset in the stack.

Comment: This only scratches the surface. Optimization does a lot more, e.g. not pushing unneeded register to the stack (caller/callee save register), branch-optimization (or removing a branch completly), optimizing pure functions, alignment and many many more. (I'm not saying that your answer is bad, just that you should link to some documentation that shows what will be done when enabling optimization)

Comment: @hellow: Of course, but I think that the OP is asking what kind of optimization can give a x100 speed boost. Improving calling convention, register renaming and such optimizations will not give such a improvement. Removing bounds checking and inlining the array indexing may do.